# Add a onClick listener on a button through browser extension and prevent default click listener of that button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclicklistener

How can I write a button click listener of a form, such that my listener runs first and existing listeners do not run at all or run after my listener?

I am trying to write a listener for the button `document.querySelector(".js-webauthn-confirm-button")` on page https://github.com/sessions/two-factor/webauthn.

My eventual goal is to use `content_script.js` to write a listener for this button through the Chrome extension. But for now, I am trying to ensure it works by running the following code in the console and clicking the button. This listener works okay but the button's original listener is also working and the original listener run first.

```
document.querySelector(".js-webauthn-confirm-button").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("Wait 2 secs")
              }, 2000); 
            });
```

I also tested it with content_script and it doesn't work. I used `"run_at": "document_start",` in the manifest file. It listens for the button but not first.

Followup tests:
I tried to test the listener on "login" button of Github and it works perfectly. However, it is of type "input", does it makes a difference?

```
document.querySelector(".js-sign-in-button").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Wait 2 secs")
            }, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
            });
```

Comment: See [this answer](/a/69503924/).